# Problem running a test with src/main and src/test

Tags: java

Newbie to Java having issue with an existing code base.

It seems Java files in /src/code are not being picked up.

Other devs here use IntelliJ, which runs tests fine out of the box (default config). I'm trying to use VSCode but also get the same result running via the terminal:

Running a test gives me a "cannot find symbol" error trying to import local classes from /src/test/... If I copy the problematic file into /src/main/... that file imports fine but error reappears with the next imported file, and so on.

Note that command clicking the 'missing' file opens its source in VSCode, so I know it's there.

import is standard:

```java
import com.foo.bar.baz.math.TestMathModelFactory;
```

File exists under:

`work/src/test/java/com/foo/bar/baz/math/TestMathModelFactory.java`

It builds if I put it under:

`work/src/main/java/com/foo/bar/baz/math/TestMathModelFactory.java`

Expect it to import, but get:

```java
RTPTest.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import com.foo.bar.baz.math.TestMathModelFactory;
                           ^
```

I know I'm doing something stupid, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: i had bad experience with java extension in vscode. it builds the classes in some other location, and screws up the build. better continue with intellij which is much much better

Comment: I guess you have to add `/src/test/` to the class path of the project. But I never used VSCODE, so you know better than me where this settings are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL, was my own Pebkac issue. I was trying to run the tests via the VScode "Code Runner" extension – which, in retrospect, has no idea how the project is set up. When I ran the tests via the "Java Test Runner" extension, they ran fine.

I told you the issue was my stupidity! Thanks for the ideas anyways!

Comment: VSCode with Java?

Comment: Yeah @Antoniossss no idea how it will go yet though, I'm a Java newbie (from webdev background). It may be a really bad idea....